# What's the diference between kernel-modules, kernel-drivers, drivers and modules?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was verifying how UL used tags for something and discovered these tags. Ok, I know that Xorg uses the term "drivers" to refer to the software that runs stuff, so kernel-drivers may be a differentiation, but the four tags seems to me like trying to convey the same information, and in fact the two that has excerpts does. Which tag should be used and for what purpose?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the kernel-drivers tag can be safely merged into drivers. I'll go ahead and do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My first impression is that [kernel-drivers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-drivers) should be merged into [drivers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drivers), and [module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) was created by someone who typed `kernel module` as separate words and grew from there. This is to be confirmed by browsing through the questions list which I haven't done yet.

Only [16 questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module+-kernel-modules+-kernel) are tagged [module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) but not [kernel-modules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-modules) or [kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel). 8 of these are about Linux kernel modules all the same. This leaves 8 questions where [module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) doesn't mean kernel module:

- Apache module: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/mod-auth-mysql-will-not-compile-under-slackware-13) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18824/localhost-htaccess-not-working-on-ubuntu) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65492/debian-installing-mod-qos-on-apache-results-in-error-on-start) [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89754/module-dependencies) Given that we don't have that many advanced Apache questions, I think these four questions can live without a tag indicating that they're about Apache modules. If you disagree, feel free to retag these questions to [apache-module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-module), but please go and look for *other* questions that should have the tag (this might warrant a separate meta discussion).
- Python module: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92830/adding-alsa-module-in-python-in-linux) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96199/different-version-of-python-cannot-find-modules) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111775/cant-find-module-six-py-when-reverse-engineering-python-project) “Module” is Python for “library”, I retagged these questions to [libraries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libraries).
- Some Sharepoint thing? [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59366/is-there-any-solution-like-sharepoint-in-linux) a question that should be closed anyway.

The remaining [module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) questions are about kernel modules, so my recommendation is that a moderator now:

1. merges [module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) into [kernel-modules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-modules);
2. removes the [module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module) synonym, which will kill that tag.

[drivers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drivers) and [kernel-modules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-modules) are different things. Many kernel modules are drivers, and many drivers are kernel modules, but some kernel modules aren't exactly drivers but more like support libraries for drivers, and conversely some software that mediates access to peripherals can be built into the main kernel image or might not run in the kernel at all. [kernel-modules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-modules) is for questions like “how do I load this module on boot?” or “how do I build this module?” while [drivers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drivers) is for questions like “how do I interact with this piece of hardware”. Of course many questions like “how should I load this module so that it recognizes my hardware” warrant both tags.

Comment: I've submitted a tag wiki edit for [tag:kernel-modules] to try to reflect your suggested usage here. I think its important to get how to use tags into the excerpt, because people asking questions will actually see it there, unlike here on meta...

Comment: The tags have already been merged (presumably by Michael). Marking as status-completed now.